# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}i^2n_in_j \ge \sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}ijn_in_j $

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-explanation

As a step in a proof, I need to show the following:

$\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}i^2n_in_j \ge \sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}ijn_in_j $

To show this, the solution states:

> But for a fixed pair $i, j$ the coefficient of $n_in_j$ on the left-side summation is $i^2+j^2$, whereas its coefficient in the right summation is $2ij$. Hence it suffices to show that $i^2 + j^2 \ge 2ij$

While I think I understand the argument and how to conclude it from here (i.e, this follows since $(i-j)^2\ge 0$) I don't understand how we get the coefficients used in this inequality. I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that $n_i n_j=n_j n_i$, therefore you need to sum two coefficients since both lead to the same type of term. Here's an example: Let's say you want to compute the $n_3 n_4$ coefficient of the sum on the left-hand side. Then you need to sum the term when $(i,j)=(3,4)$ with the term when $(i,j)=(4,3)$. This gives you $(3^2+4^2)n_3 n_4$.

---

If you still do not understand, then perhaps here is a simpler way of reasoning. Write
$$S:=\sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r i^2 n_i n_j.$$
Relabelling the indices (the variables $i$ and $j$ are just dummy variables) and changing the order of summation (justified, since the sums are finite) also shows that
$$S=\sum_{j=1}^r \sum_{i=1}^r j^2 n_j n_i=\sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r j^2 n_i n_j.$$
Hence one has by the inequality $i^2+j^2\geq 2ij$:
$$2S=\sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r (i^2+j^2)n_i n_j\geq \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r 2ijn_i n_j,$$
Dividing by $2$ gives the result you need to prove.